# Content devide in 3parts IE error

Tags: html, css

I have a content with Title, image and description. I have 3 differents contents, which i have to put side by side. What would be better do achive this ? I did with `<ul>`. But the image wasnts below title, and description below image, so i just but after `<li></li>` a break, and it worked. But in IE it doesnt.

Here is what i got - > http://jsfiddle.net/5xfR9/12/

```
 <div id="content">
   <ul>
     <li>
       <h3>Custom clearance</h3><br/>
       <img src="..." style="width:360px; height: 160px;" alt="Custom clearance" /><br/>
       <p style="width:360px;">...<br /><a href="#" style="float:right; padding-top:10px;">Learn more <img src="images/arrow.png" alt="learn more" style="width:6px; height:9px; border: 0px;"/></a><br/>
   </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3>Cargo Inspections</h3><br/>
        <img src="..." style="width:360px; height: 160px;" alt="Custom clearance" /><br/>
        <p style="width:360px; padding">...<br /><a href="#" style="float:right; padding-top:10px;">Learn more <img src="images/arrow.png" alt="learn more" style="width:6px; height:9px; border: 0px;"/></a>
        </p><br/>   
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3>Our Location</h3><br/>
        <img src="..." style="width:360px; height: 160px;" alt="Custom clearance" /><br/>
        <p style="width:360px;">....<br /><a href="#" style="float:right;  padding-top:10px;">Learn more <img src="images/arrow.png" alt="learn more" style="width:6px; height:9px; border: 0px;"/></a>
        </p><br/>
       </li>
      </ul>     
    </div>
```

using this CSS

```
#content {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 450px;
    display: block;
    padding-bottom:40px;
}
#content ul li {
    display: inline;    
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    min-width:32%;
}


#content  ul li > h3 {
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    font-family: gothamlight;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
}
#content  ul li > img {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    padding: 0px 25px 0px 25px;
}

#content  ul li > p {
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 1.3;
    display:block;
    color: #404041;
    float:left;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
    display: block;
}
```

I guess I did it wrong, I put `<br />` after a `<li></li>`, so that content would be vertical.

But of course IE is smart and it shows Content 1  for the whole width page, and other content is after the first one.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: maybe you draw with paint what you want ;)

Comment: try using width instead of min-width for your li